# android crashes screen rotation

Tags: android, image-processing, user-interface, memory-leaks

I've been working on this ap for a client. We are pretty much ready to release it, but in testing I realize it crashes pretty much at any point onPause(), onResume() are called. Specifically getting a text, or rotating the screen. Or in some cases simply going between screens. Every time it gives me an out of memory error. So obviously the images for the background, buttons etc, are to blame, as they are the only elements that use any real amount of memory. So I've stripped it down to a completely bland application with just 2 buttons with images on it.

The buttons are 60k PNGs which have been optimized for mobile devices via photoshop.

I have done a lot of research, and spent time in #android-dev on freenode. I'm not seeing anything to fix this problem.

I process the background according to the documents on the android dev. This part is not in this code, but otherwise it would be immanently added to the onCreate() method as soon as I can get it to work with a blank ap with 2 buttons. (with the appropriate view)

currently not in the application, but will be added back

```
private void setNewPoolBackground() {
    setContentView(<FOO>);
    Bitmap image = getImage(R.drawable.background);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(image);
    rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (<FOO>);
    rLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
private Bitmap getImage(int img) {
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getResources()
            .openRawResource(img), null, o2);
    return image;
}
```

CODE: TestRotation.java

```
package test.t;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TestRotateActivity extends Activity {

    Bitmap image;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //setNewPoolBackground();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //View v 
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/group_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5pt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8pt"
        android:layout_marginRight="7pt"
        android:layout_marginTop="50pt"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" 
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlayGN"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >






            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvGroupTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="group_title" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/group_title"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <requestFocus />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
         >


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/newUserList"
                android:layout_width="233dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/group_title"
                android:layout_weight="2.44"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addgbutton"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="25pt"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/moremembutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/finish"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/moremembutton"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="25pt"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addgbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
        android:background="@drawable/addmember"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler" >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LOG

```
09-19 03:17:57.546: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 806 objects / 56864 bytes in 45ms
09-19 03:17:57.876: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 206 objects / 9736 bytes in 37ms
09-19 03:19:00.135: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 707 objects / 25800 bytes in 94ms
09-19 03:19:00.545: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 28 objects / 1624 bytes in 33ms
09-19 03:19:06.885: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 597 objects / 24008 bytes in 37ms
09-19 03:19:07.605: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 523 objects / 31384 bytes in 32ms
09-19 03:19:07.916: D/dalvikvm(278): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 84 objects / 3816 bytes in 32ms
09-19 03:19:19.346: E/dalvikvm-heap(278): 3122676-byte external allocation too large for this process.
09-19 03:19:19.355: E/GraphicsJNI(278): VM won't let us allocate 3122676 bytes
09-19 03:19:19.375: D/AndroidRuntime(278): Shutting down VM
09-19 03:19:19.375: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.t/test.t.TestRotateActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3815)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at test.t.TestRotateActivity.onCreate(TestRotateActivity.java:21)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 12 more
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:65)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 23 more
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:327)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:69)
09-19 03:19:19.455: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OOM error is not an unexpected exception in android if we are playing with lot of bitmap and large images.Since android phones and tab come in many heap sizes its bit difficult to make it compactible with all the deveices.Most of the android devices have low heap memory.through code we can allocate it because we only have limited acess to clear the memory.After each process call the `System.gc()` and alocate the unused memory using garbagecollector.Still its not sure that all the unused memory is cleared.Recycle all the bitmaps after your usage `bitmap.recycle()`.Also dont use many bitmaps in the app.Built an app with very less number of bitmaps,when you use it recycle it and use it again and again.
You can unbind all the drawables from the views when you leave an activity.

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            try {
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
                ((BitmapDrawable) view.getBackground()).getBitmap().recycle();
                view.destroyDrawingCache();
                view.notifyAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }
```

You can also deallocate all the unused memory through code..

```
public void clearAllocatedMemory() {
        try {
            List.removeAllViews();
            adapter.releaseAllMemory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        adapter = null;
    }
```

I think doing all these will allocate your memory to the maximum and you can reduce the chances of this exception.

Comment: Good answer. So I would call this at OnPause() and OnStop() I assume. Now I see why it was 'exploding' on me!

Comment: If you got it correct accept the ans and upvoting.It do adds points to we both.

Answer (score 2):

```
   if your android:targetSdkVersion="12" or less
   add this in you each Activitiy declaration in manitest.xml
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

      if your  android:targetSdkVersion="13" or more
     add this in you each Activitiy declaration in manitest.xml
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```